# How can I upload code to a PIC microcontroller?

Tags: pic, ftdi, pic-ccs

I'm using a PIC18F4620 and I wrote the code in CCS C compiler. I found several tutorials on uploading code to the microcontroller but they all use MPlab X and PicKit. How can I upload the code to the microcontroller without MPlab X or PicKit?

Edit: I want to elaborate the question: I have this protect where I have to write the code, design the circuit and, design the PCB layout of a digital clock. Here is the PCB design:

[image]

The problem is, I have no experience in this type of job so I don't really have any programmer or any other hardware(I'm an intern). I thought someting similar to USART may be the answer. I would appreciate if you could help.

Comment: do you already own programmer hardware? Can't really do it without, unless your PIC came preloaded with some bootloader.

Comment: I ask because you say "I'm using…" and that sounds like you already have a setting where you *can* program it (otherwise you'd be saying "I'm planning to use…"  or something). The complexity and cost of programming devices often make microcontroller decisions, especially in low-volume (as in: a single device, 10 devices) settings, where the programmer hardware cost and -annoyance can outweigh advantages of a microcontroller. The PIC1… microcontrollers are definitely not the easiest nor cheapest to be flashed microcontrollers on the market.

Comment: The fact that "ftdi" has been chosen as a tag might be a hint that it came preloaded with UART over USB bootloader. Either way, we need more information on what particular evaluation kit that OP may be using

Comment: Is there a reason your board only has copper on one side? I see a lot of 0-ohm links being used as jumpers; why not use backside copper?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a bootloader to program it via UART so you don't need PicKit.

But you still need to program the UART bootloader with PicKit, so you are back to needing a PicKit anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using the [PIC18F4620 Embedded Ethernet Development Kit](https://www.ccsinfo.com/product_info.php?products_id=embethkit)  and bought the Proto-Board only offering, it doesn't include a programmer. CCS offer their own [programmers and tools](https://www.ccsinfo.com/programmers-debuggers.php) with the cheapest programmer [ICD-U64 Debugger/Programmer](https://www.ccsinfo.com/product_info.php?products_id=icd_u64) currently not in stock at time of writing.

I strongly suggest you to upgrade to [MPLAB X IDE](https://www.microchip.com/en-us/tools-resources/develop/mplab-x-ide) and XC8 compiler which is far superior and has a free edition of [XC8 compiler](https://www.microchip.com/en-us/tools-resources/develop/mplab-xc-compilers/downloads-documentation#XC8) and PIC-Kit 4 which has programming and debug capability, is cheaper than the CCS programmer option and has >1000 in stock at time of writing on [Microchip website](https://www.microchip.com/en-us/development-tool/PG164140) and many other distributors such as [Farnell](https://uk.farnell.com/microchip/pg164140/in-ckt-debugger-programmer-pic/dp/2840654).

Comment: We use the CCS compiler with MPLAB X and Microchip Pickit, so you won't have to re-write your code.  But as @Justme says, you still have to buy a programmer (Pickit or ICD).

Answer (score 0):

The cheapest Microchip programmer is the [Microchip SNAP](https://www.microchip.com/en-us/development-tool/PG164100#). I couldn't find a link to the list of supported devices so make sure your device is supported before buying it. It's been a while since I looked into it.